# Getting an camel-maven error while running my project using maven

Tags: maven, apache-camel, pom.xml

I am getting the following error while running my project with this command: mvn -e camel:run

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.camel:camel-maven-plugin:2.10.4:run (default-cli) on
> project bullshit: nul  l: MojoExecutionException:
> org.apache.camel.spring.Main -> [Help 1]
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
> execute goal org.apache.camel:camel-maven-plugin:2.10.  4:run
> (default-cli) on project bullshit: null  at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.
> java:51)  at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)  at
> org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)  at
> org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)  at
> org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)  at
> org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)  at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
> at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
> at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
> at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
> Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException  at
> org.apache.camel.maven.RunMojo.execute(RunMojo.java:482)  at
> org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
> ... 19 more  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.apache.camel.spring.Main  at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)  at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)  at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)  at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)  at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)  at
> org.apache.camel.maven.RunMojo$1.run(RunMojo.java:434)  at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Here's what I have for dependency in my pom.xml file:

```
<properties> 
<camel.version>2.10.4</camel.version> 
</properties> 
<dependency> 
<groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId> 
<artifactId>camel-core</artifactId> 
<version>${camel.version}</version> 
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
<groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId> 
<artifactId>camel-core-osgi</artifactId> 
<version>${camel.version}</version> 
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
<groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId> 
<artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId> 
<version>${camel.version}</version> 
<scope>compile</scope> 
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
<groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId> 
<artifactId>camel-quartz</artifactId> 
<version>${camel.version}</version> 
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
<groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId> 
<artifactId>camel-mina</artifactId> 
<version>${camel.version}</version> 
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
<groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId> 
<artifactId>camel-spring-integration</artifactId> 
<version>${camel.version}</version> 
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
<groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId> 
<artifactId>camel-test</artifactId> 
<version>${camel.version}</version> 
<scope>test</scope> 
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
<groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId> 
<artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId> 
<version>${camel.version}</version> 
<scope>test</scope> 
</dependency>
```

Error after removing scope.

I removed the scope. I am getting this error:Error occurred while running main from:

> org.apache.camel.spring.Main java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.apache.camel.spring.Main
> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
> at org.apache.camel.maven.RunMojo$1.run(RunMojo.java:434)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a classpath issue, this class is not found `org.apache.camel.spring.Main`, which is from the `camel-spring` dependency. So you should remove the compile scope, eg just use

```
<dependency> 
<groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId> 
<artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId> 
<version>${camel.version}</version> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: please take a look at my post again. I have updated my post.  I removed the scope and am still getting same error.

Comment: Sometimes weird errors can happen if you have mixed versions of Camel on the classpth. So make sure they are all the same version. And make sure camel-spring JAR is on the classpath. And how do you run your Maven project. Also study the examples that come with Camel and learn how to run them.

Comment: `compile` is the default scope used if none is specified, so adding or removing this scope doesn't have an influence.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error recently. Changing the target SDK to an OpenSDK got things working again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A required dependency is missing in your pom.xml. Please add:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-spring-main</artifactId>
  <version>${camel.version}</version> 
</dependency>
```

I'm using camel version 3.20.0